# How to create a script that given a list of websites it uses their search functionality to fetch information?

Tags: javascript, php, search, fetch

I'm trying to build a website that is simply a platform where you can aggregate information from other websites. It would be a central repository that search information in other repositories and displays it. Is there standard way to this? I've been looking around but i wasn't able to find anything relevant.I would like an implementation based on javascript or even php but I'm open to other tools that could do it easier.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm not trying to get a full implementation of how it's done. I'm trying to be pointed in the right direction to start it, or to where I can get information on how to do it, since I sincerely have no clue at this moment. Thanks

Comment: Share anything what you have tried so that we can help you.Asking plain question to do the whole job will not get you any answers at all..!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to have the job done for me, maybe I wasn't completely clear. I'm trying to understand if this is possible in the first place and if there's something similar done that i can use as model to help me get started since I couldn't find anything that could help me. At first i thought about creating a web crawler but after reading about them I realized that is not what I'm looking for. I just need to be pointed in the right direction since I have no clue right now.

Comment: Use an API to do your Job..This may help : https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-sitesearch

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the websites you are trying to get information from don't have some structured data response and have only html response it will be really difficult. You would have to extract those data from html text. That sound quite undoable to me

Comment: It isn't possible to provide the script a website's url and have the script filling the input field, submit the form and return the results from the website's response?

Comment: You can show iframe of the website. But how can you recognize what is data and what is style? You can fill form or to be more accurate send the same request as the form. Problem is with the answer. How you gona proccess it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are underestimating the difficulty of your problem.
You cannot simply "use" the search function on a website.
I recommend you to gather API information and use that to grab info.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what do you mean about gather API information and use that to grab information?

Comment: Try and get API access to the websites you are trying to pull data from, then use the APIS to get your needed data.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You want to automate form filling & Submission..!

**Solution :** Ahaa..! Seems like you are looking for something which can automate form filling and submitting you may need to check Firefox Extension namely as `iMacros` It can do the job for you and ever more better if you want complex jobs so then you may need to use **JavaScript** with it.It works with JavaScript for more complex jobs..!

### iMacros (FireFox Extension) :

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/

**iMacros Simple Use Code :**

This codes Visit Google Search Engine and search for "How to write iMacros Script" and then shows all the results automtically once you run the Macros so it does everything automatically :

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=about:newtab
URL GOTO=www.google.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT=how<SP>to<SP>write<SP>an<SP>imacros<SP>script
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=NAME:btnG
```

**Video Guide**

#### How iMacros Works In FireFox :

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ3HE_hpFMc

Comment: @António Quadrado : Take a look at this one..! Let me know if it solves your problem..!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for specially since it's a browser specific extension. I'll have to keep searching and maybe rethink my approach to the problem... Ideally I would have a search input field in my application and when submited the controller would pick the input value and run it has input in all the search input fields of all the url's that would be stored in the application, and return the results or the direct url to the results... Maybe I should rethink this...

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado : As you wish,I just gave you a way to do the automation job.!

Comment: Yes, and I thank you very much. It can be of use eventually!

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado : No Problem..Don't hesitate to ask for anymore help at all..!

Comment: Of course! I'll continue to develop the idea and I'll ask for help when I have  it more structured.

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado : If it solved your problem so then make sure that you mark the answer and the question will be solved so that no one else is confused..!